# Admob AdBanner loading causes fragment to deform

Tags: android, android-fragments, admob

In my app there are 4 `Buttons` on the main screen and each button opens a new `Activity`. Each `Activity` contains a `Fragment` and at the end of `Fragment` there is `Admob`banner. Basic layout of each `Fragment` is like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
//some stuff here
</LinearLayout>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adViewEncodeManual"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_bottom_home_screen_banner">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

`HomescreenActivity` uses `TableLayout` instead of `linearLayout`. I am loading add on `onActivityCreated` inside each `Fragment`.

```
   @Override
public void onActivityCreated( Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if(localAdView == null)
    { // if prevents a loadRequest again when activity is resumed

        localAdView = (AdView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.adViewHome);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("F0554446AEA73E5599774C945E9B99F1").build();
        localAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

}
```

Banners loadup fine on each `Activity` but if i switch from 1 `Activity` to another again and again i get distorted display with random broken `View`s. It gets fixed when i click any where.

Problem is with banners only because when i turn off internet everything is fine.

Any advice guys ?

Table_layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.apps.toffeesoft.easyqrReader.HomeScreenActivityFragment">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adViewHome"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/home_background"

    >
    <TableRow

        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnScan"
            android:elevation="@dimen/abc_control_corner_material"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-7dp"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/home_scan_heading"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_image_camera_alt" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCreate"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-6dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/home_create_plain_heading"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/create_qr_plain"
            />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCreateContact"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-7dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/home_create_contact_qr_heading"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/contact_image"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnQrHistory"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/qr_history"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/history"
            />


    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<!--
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adViewHome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_bottom_home_screen_banner">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt of all your general Layout for `Fragment`s has no relation to its `View`s. Your `ViewGroup` `LinearLayout` that contain _some stuff_has  `Height` `match_parent`, looking at that, that is suppose to fill up the whole entire screen **BUT** you have `Admob` `View` that is being position at the bottom in the Parent `ViewGroup` `RelativeLayout` and that too is `match_parent` so yes your `View`s will have no positioning.

Instead make your `LinearLayout` a ScrollView that is if your `View`s are enough to fill up the Screen or simply let the `LinearLayout` lie above the`Admob`

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_above="@+id/theidoftheadmob"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   //some stuff here
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Elltz, Thanks for your suggestion . I tried both of your suggestions but same result :( . I even tried putting Ad. banner inside activity layout instead of fragment layout but again same result. I also changed layout_height to wrap_parent but no effect.

Comment: can you post a pic of how it looks@Vikram i will vote you up so you get enough rep

Comment: i still could not add image. I have uploaded it at this link http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=xf4x2s&s=8#.VVEwudqqqko

Comment: wait a minute, do you have an `Adview` in `Activity` layout and also Fragment layout? from your post i see this as the id of your admob in your xml `adViewEncodeManual` and in your `Fragment` class the `onActivityCreate()` method i see `(AdView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.adViewHome);` which means you are loading the Add in a different layout in your Activity layout. not your Fragment Layout. do you see what i mean? if you still do not get me post your activity layout xml@Vikram

Comment: Earlier i had banner in fragment then i moved it to activity.

Comment: oh okay, but the reason you are having a layout like that its because your `Adview` hav overlayed your `Fragment` layout and you use tablelayout right? do you know what lastly post that layout@Vikram

Comment: Admob IDs are fine i accidentally copied code from different `fragment` , sorry about that. I created a test project i made 2 activities and a ad. banner at the bottom of each `activity`. If i switch between these activities also(3-4 times at a fast pace) i get similar result. I guess this is happening because `loadAd` is called again and again. In the test project there is just a `RelativeLayout` containg a button and ad banner at the bottom.